# Encountered a Dart Analysis Server error.in Android studio

Tags: flutter, dart

I don't know why this error is happening.

1.I updated my Flutter sdk Yesterday.

2.This error displaying after 24 hours of latest update

3.How can I solve this error

[image: Here is the screenshot error]

Comment: Can you run `flutter analyze` from the command line?

Comment: This error got solved automatically thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary error. No need to worry about this error..

It will automatically go away..Just focus on your work.